# Why is my html displaying my sidebar and nav twice using laravel?

Tags: html, laravel

Not a native English speaker so prepare for typos.

I was wondering why my nav and sidebar are being shown twice on my html page when i look at it in a browser.

So you'd know what I'm talking 'bout here's a screenshot:

[image]

Right now my main page looks like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Schadedossier @yield('title')</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://soshandyman.blob.core.windows.net/themes/bs4-insurance.css">
</head>
<body>
<!--wrapper(the thing around the sidebar and the nav)-->
<div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
<!--sidebar-->
<div class="bg-light border-right collapse" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-heading">logo</div>
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Tussenpersoon</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Woning</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Schadedossier</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Data schadedossier</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Verzekeringsnemer</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Contract raadplegen</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
<!--page content-->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar-wrapper" aria-controls="sidebar-wrapper" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="aangifte-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#aangifte" aria-controls="aangifte">Aangifte</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="details-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#details">Details</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="overzicht-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#overzicht">Overzicht</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="evaluatie-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#evaluatie">Evaluatie</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
<!--start tab content (here starts the nav aangifte and so on)-->
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
@yield('content', View::make('childAangifte'))
</div>
<!--end page content-->
</div>
<!--endsidebar-->
</div>
<!--endwrapper-->
<!--incert bootstrapscripts here-->
</body>
```

Then this is my child's code:

```
@extends('welcome')
@section('title')
aangifte
@endsection
<!--incert html-->
@endsection
```

Anyway I'm having trouble with this because this is not the only child i need to display but if this will form an issue every time then I rather want to know before I try to get the other ones to work.

Also what option would be better to use switch or if to go to the other children?
Thanks a bunch and sorry for the terrible formatting.

Comment: For the sidebar, you can use `@include`. for the content which is dynamic, you can use `yield`

Comment: I think u missunderstood me in this case i might need to edit my post a bit but the side bar is already coded in my html 'welcome' page and isnt being included not yielded to.

Comment: You've censored all the useful bits. How are we supposed to help you find a bug in `<!--sidebar-->` if you've hidden what it contains?

Comment: i have just edited it i did it like that because the code didn't want to register the code when i first made the post. i'm sorry for frustrating you or others, but having this be a problem and me not knowing how to solve it is because i am new to stackoverflow. I tried my best and i hope this helps.